# Joint cost function with Lagrangian

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, convex-optimization

How can I formulate joint cost functions if Lagrangians are involved? For example, if I have

$J_1 = \|\mathbf{Ax} - \mathbf{b}\|^2_2 + \lambda f$ and $J_2 = \|\mathbf{Cx} - \mathbf{d}\|^2_2$,

would it be correct to do something like

$J_{12} = \|
\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{Ax} - \mathbf{b}) + \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{Cx} - \mathbf{d})\|^2_2 + \lambda (\frac{f}{2})$?

I'm not sure if I can just effectively shift the Lagrange multiplier term.